# My Bootstrap menu links are working on mobile

Tags: javascript, wordpress, bootstrap-4

WordPress website with Bootstrap menu works fine on desktop but on mobile the dropdown menu links don't do anything. The hamburger button opens and closes the dropdown menu and sub-menus expand properly, so at first glance it looks like it is good, but when you click on a sub-menu item nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a slimmed down copy of the generated menu code:

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation navbar navbar-expand-lg" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="skip-link"><a class="screen-reader-text" href="#content">Skip to content</a></div>
        <div id="mobile-header" class="site-header clearfix" role="banner">
            <div class="flex">
                <div class="brand">
                    <a href="/"><img  alt="The Aha! Connection" data-src="https://www.website.com/wp-content/themes/aha%213.0/img/AHA-mobile-logo.png" class="lazyload" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="><noscript><img src="https://www.website.com/wp-content/themes/aha%213.0/img/AHA-mobile-logo.png" alt="The Aha! Connection"></noscript></a>
                </div>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar" aria-controls="bs-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="btn-txt">MENU</span>
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bs-navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center">
            <ul id="menu-menu" class="navbar-nav mr-auto" itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
                <li  id="menu-item-111922" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-111922 nav-item"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" id="menu-item-dropdown-111922"><span itemprop="name">Aha! Originals</span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-item-dropdown-111922">
                        <li  id="menu-item-111924" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-111924 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="https://www.website.com/category/originals/audra-originals/" class="dropdown-item"><span itemprop="name">Audra Originals</span></a></li>
                        <li  id="menu-item-111925" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-111925 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="https://www.website.com/category/originals/audras-fitness-blog/" class="dropdown-item"><span itemprop="name">Audra&#8217;s Fitness Blog</span></a></li>
                        <li  id="menu-item-111923" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-111923 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="https://www.website.com/category/originals/ask-tatiana/" class="dropdown-item"><span itemprop="name">Ask Tatiana</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li  id="menu-item-54638" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-54638 nav-item"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" id="menu-item-dropdown-54638"><span itemprop="name">Businesses</span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-item-dropdown-54638">
                        <li  id="menu-item-232" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-232 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="https://www.website.com/category/advertisements/" class="dropdown-item"><span itemprop="name">Advertisements</span></a></li>
                        <li  id="menu-item-9172" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-9172 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="https://www.website.com/category/deals/" class="dropdown-item"><span itemprop="name">Deals / Specials</span></a></li>
                        <li  id="menu-item-57748" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-57748 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="https://www.website.com/directory/" class="dropdown-item"><span itemprop="name">Directory</span></a></li>
                        <li  id="menu-item-111933" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-111933 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="https://www.website.com/category/business/giveaways/" class="dropdown-item"><span itemprop="name">Giveaways</span></a></li>
                        <li  id="menu-item-9178" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-9178 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="https://www.website.com/category/recommendations/" class="dropdown-item"><span itemprop="name">Recommendations</span></a></li>
                        <li  id="menu-item-57788" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-57788 nav-item"><a itemprop="url" href="https://www.website.com/advertising-directory-recommendations/" class="dropdown-item"><span itemprop="name">Submit A Business Listing</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

You can [test it here](https://www.theahaconnection.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like certain list elements are calling a function when clicked:

```
function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).next('.dropdown-menu li > .dropdown-menu').length) {
    $(this).next('.dropdown-menu li > .dropdown-menu').toggle();
  }
  $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu li > .dropdown-menu').hide();
  })
}
```

The preventDefault() method stops a link from loading when a link element is clicked. **Solution: Simply remove:**

```
e.preventDefault()
```

Comment: PS: The code snippet can be found in index.php!

Comment: I removed the code, but now menu branches that have 3 levels (like Classifieds) are not functional. The first click on menu toggle opens the menu. The second click on "Classifieds" opens that sub-menu, but the next click on the item with the sub-menu indicator triggers the link to that parent item instead of opening 3rd level menu. Actually both things happen, but the navigation occurs before you have a chance to view or click on the 3rd level items.

Comment: @draney The list element that opens the third level sub-menu needs to be disabled as a link on mobile to work because it isn't possible to hover over a link. The best way to solve this is by showing one element on mobile that has the link disabled, and another that has a link on desktop. You could also add something like this: `if (window.innerWidth < 768) {document.querySelector(".current_page_ancestor").removeAttribute("href");}`

Comment: WOW WOW WOW! That fixed it. THANKS for your help!!!

Comment: No problem! Happy coding!